# Cannot to install Composer by command line in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I cannot install Composer on Ubuntu 14.04 with:

> sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

I got error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

> Current PHP version:

```
PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2015 12:47:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Which part of the `issues listed below` don't you understand?

Comment: I understand but I still cannot install it. Could you help me?

Comment: How is PHP installed on your system?  MAMP? Homebrew? yum?

Comment: How did you install PHP In the first place? Did you use apt-get? Because json (at least) should be installed by default

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-json

Comment: Yes, I did. I got: php5-json is already the newest version. But still cannot install composer with above command line.